# Predict the nature of the curve

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

$$f(x)=\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}e^{u^2\over x}du$$
Hence predict the graph of $f(x)$:
[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on what to try?

Comment: Hint: Look at the derivative of f(x).

Comment: Is that an $x$ in the denominator of the exponential? Are you sure that's what you want there?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The derivative of $f(x)$ can be computed using the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement).

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{\frac{u^2}{x}}\,du\\
=e^{\frac{(\sqrt{x})^2}{x}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{\frac{u^2}{x}}\right)\,du.$$